# Read/Write for Flutter App from SMB Server

Tags: flutter, server, protocols, smb

is there a way to Read/Write from a Flutter App to a SMB Server?
I'm working on a personal project, I've tried http/Dio package but don't support the SMB Protocol.
Please, Help me guys.

```
  Future<void> _getData() async {
    var client = Dio();
    try {
      var serverPath = 'smb://192.168.1.30/';
      var response = await client.post(
        serverPath,
        data: {'user': 'username', 'password': 'password'},
      );
      var data = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.data));
      debugPrint('data $data');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: why don't you post tried code?

Comment: @gretal Updated

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [libdsm](https://pub.dev/packages/libdsm) and  you also need to embed an [http server](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver) in your app

Comment: I have the libdsm but I don't know how create a http server inside the app, can u help me?